# Add Bings maps to html js

Tags: javascript, azure, maps

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jfdhL.jpg)I used  the below code and passed location.
But it doesn't return any map.I replaced "New York" with variable.
console.log does show the value but somehow map is not being displayed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/v8-web-control/map-control-concepts/search-module-examples/basic-geocode-example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
 <body>
Location: <input type="text" name="a" id="a"><br>
<button onclick="GetMap(document.getElementById('a').value )">Submit</button>
</body>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, searchManager;
 
    function GetMap(qry) {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'MY Key'
        });
var qry1=qry;
        //Make a request to geocode New York, NY.
 
        geocodeQuery(qry1);

    }

    function geocodeQuery(query) {
console.log(query);
        //If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
        if (!searchManager) {
            //Create an instance of the search manager and call the geocodeQuery function again.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                geocodeQuery(query);
            });
        } else {
            var searchRequest = {
                where: query,
                callback: function (r) {
                    //Add the first result to the map and zoom into it.
                    if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) {
                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(r.results[0].location);
                        map.entities.push(pin);

                        map.setView({ bounds: r.results[0].bestView });
                    }
                },
                errorCallback: function (e) {
                    //If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                    alert("No results found.");
                }
            };

            //Make the geocode request.
            searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `<head>` section of the HTML document should not contain a `<body>` tag. Move the body-related HTML elements to the `<body>` section.

- You are trying to create a map with the ID `myMap`, but I didn't see the HTML element with that ID. You need to add a `div` element with the ID `myMap` to your HTML.

**Updated code:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        var map, searchManager;

        function Search() {
            if (!searchManager) {
                // Create an instance of the search manager and perform the search.
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                    searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                    Search();
                });
            } else {
                // Remove any previous results from the map.
                map.entities.clear();

                // Get the user's query and geocode it.
                var query = document.getElementById('searchTbx').value;
                geocodeQuery(query);
            }
        }

        function GetMap() {
            map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
                credentials: 'Your Bing Maps Key'
            });

            // You don't need to make a request to geocode New York, NY here.
            // You can leave this function empty.
        }

        function geocodeQuery(query) {
            // If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
            if (!searchManager) {
                // Create an instance of the search manager and call the geocodeQuery function again.
                Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                    searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                    geocodeQuery(query);
                });
            } else {
                var searchRequest = {
                    where: query,
                    callback: function (r) {
                        // Add the first result to the map and zoom into it.
                        if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) {
                            var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(r.results[0].location);
                            map.entities.push(pin);

                            map.setView({ bounds: r.results[0].bestView });
                        }
                    },
                    errorCallback: function (e) {
                        // If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                        alert("No results found.");
                    }
                };

                // Make the geocode request.
                searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
            }
        }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='searchTbx' type='text' />
    <input type='button' value='Search' onclick='Search()' />
    <br />
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id='output' style="margin-left:10px;float:left;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

- I updated the script source to use HTTPS for loading the Bing Maps API and also I made to call `GetMap` as the `callback` parameter in the script source to ensure that the map is initialized after the Bing Maps API is loaded.

Comment: When I search for New York ,I get the error                                                Gyzn-Omw0bFKVY3BfZ181U0olyo.br.js:1                                                                  
          Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'instanceAsync')
    at n.geocode (Gyzn-Omw0bFKVY3BfZ181U0olyo.br.js:1:3239)
    at geocodeQuery (mapsgeocode.html:45:31)
    at GetMap (mapsgeocode.html:21:13)
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (mapsgeocode.html:9:66)

Comment: It's happening because the Bing Maps API is not fully initialized or loaded when you call the Search function, and it's trying to access properties on searchManager which is null or not properly initialized.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type='text/javascript'>
    var map, searchManager;

  function Search() {
        if (!searchManager) {
            //Create an instance of the search manager and perform the search.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                Search()
            });
        } else {
            //Remove any previous results from the map.
            map.entities.clear();

            //Get the users query and geocode it.
            var query = document.getElementById('searchTbx').value;
            geocodeQuery(query);
        }
    }

    function GetMap() {
        map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
            credentials: 'Bing Key'
        });

        //Make a request to geocode New York, NY.
        geocodeQuery("New York, NY");
    }

    function geocodeQuery(query) {
        //If search manager is not defined, load the search module.
        if (!searchManager) {
            //Create an instance of the search manager and call the geocodeQuery function again.
            Microsoft.Maps.loadModule('Microsoft.Maps.Search', function () {
                searchManager = new Microsoft.Maps.Search.SearchManager(map);
                geocodeQuery(query);
            });
        } else {
            var searchRequest = {
                where: query,
                callback: function (r) {
                    //Add the first result to the map and zoom into it.
                    if (r && r.results && r.results.length > 0) {
                        var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(r.results[0].location);
                        map.entities.push(pin);

                        map.setView({ bounds: r.results[0].bestView });
                    }
                },
                errorCallback: function (e) {
                    //If there is an error, alert the user about it.
                    alert("No results found.");
                }
            };

            //Make the geocode request.
            searchManager.geocode(searchRequest);
        }
    }
    </script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap' async defer></script>
</head>
<body>
    <input id='searchTbx' type='text'/>
    <input type='button'value='Search' onclick='Search()'/>
    <br/>
    <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;float:left;"></div>
    <div id='output' style="margin-left:10px;float:left;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Removed the geocode request for "New York, NY" in the GetMap function. You don't need this, as you are allowing the user to enter a search query.